# Request laravel não retorna input file

Tags: php, laravel

Por que não consigo pegar o arquivo da View?

Tenho um formulário que direciona pra uma rota. Entre outros atributos, tenho um upload de arquivos. Este upload de arquivos é o único atributo que não aparece na `request`.

```
<label for="recipient" class="control-label">Foto:</label>
 <input id="foto" type="file" name="foto" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @if ($errors->has('foto'))
    <span class="help-block">
      <strong>{{ $errors->first('foto') }}</strong>
    </span>
 @endif
</div>
```

No controller, tenho:

```
dd($this->request->all());
```

Isso retorna todos os atributos, mas nem aparece o 'foto'.

Também já tentei:

```
dd($request->file('foto'));
```

O que retorna `null` mesmo com um arquivo selecionado.

Comment: no form esta habilitado envio de email? p.x: `{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/form', 'files' => true)) }}`

Comment: Email ou arquivo? Obrigado pela resposta. Estou usando a tag html form normal sem facade. Como seria em HTML?

Comment: o `enctype="multipart/form-data"` não é na `input` `file` é na tag `form`, exemplo, `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ....>` um exemplo do formulário: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: Sim, está habilitado no form.

Comment: Tá usando ajax pra mandar pro php  ou submit no form?

Comment: @GabrielAugusto de uma conferida na resposta que postei, caso ainda assim seu problema não seja resolvido, poste seu form completo e o conteúdo obtido com o DD do `$request`

Answer (score 6):

O seu `input` está correto exceto pelo fato do `enctype="multipart/form-data"` este é um atributo do `form` e não do `input`

Porém com o `form` correto este não atrapalha no envio

Assim, apesar de não ter postado o seu `form`, o erro deve estar neste ou na sua rota, para fazer um pequeno teste coloquei neste `form`:

```
<form action="api/annex" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="recipient" class="control-label">Foto:</label>
    <input id="foto" type="file" name="foto" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @if ($errors->has('foto'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('foto') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

E este funcionou corretamente, como demonstro abaixo:

```
Request {#39 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#123 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#124 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#41 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#40 ▶}
  +query: ParameterBag {#47 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#44 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#43 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "foto" => UploadedFile {#28 ▼
        -test: false
        -originalName: "Dassad.png"
        -mimeType: "image/png"
        -size: 346505
        -error: 0
        path: "/tmp"
        filename: "phpJRjAf5"
        basename: "phpJRjAf5"
        pathname: "/tmp/phpJRjAf5"
        extension: ""
        realPath: "/tmp/phpJRjAf5"
        aTime: 2017-12-28 17:26:39
        mTime: 2017-12-28 17:26:39
        cTime: 2017-12-28 17:26:39
        inode: 1079759
        size: 346505
        perms: 0100600
        owner: 33
        group: 33
        type: "file"
        writable: true
        readable: true
        executable: false
        file: true
        dir: false
        link: false
      }
    ]
  }
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#42 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#45 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/api/annex"
  #requestUri: "/apiapp/public/api/annex"
  #baseUrl: "/apiapp/public"
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: null
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isClientIpsValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: "/apiapp/public"
  format: "html"
}
```

Sendo assim confira no seu `form` se esta com o atributo

**`enctype="multipart/form-data"`**

Caso ainda não funcione confira no seu form se está com o método correto:

**`method="post"`**

Caso ainda não funcione confira sua rota se está com o método correto, ex:

```
Route::resource('annex', 'AnnexController', [
    'only' => [
            'store',
    ]
]);
```

ou

```
Route::post('annex', 'AnnexController@store');
```

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente está usando Ajax para mandar os dados para o controller. Neste caso, como existe um input do tipo file o ajax nao enviará o conteudo do mesmo.

Use FormData ao inves de serialize. a baixo mostro um trecho de codigo no qual envio dados de um formulário que contem um input do tipo file.

```js
$('#btnAddProjecto').click(function () {
            var data = new FormData($('#myFormProjecto')[0]);// codigo antigo $('#myFormProjecto').serialize();
           
            $.ajax({
                type: 'jax',
                method: 'post',
                url: "{{ route('projecto.store')}}",
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (resposta) {
                    alert(resposta);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                   
                }
            });
        });
```